# Using Notepad++ to search/replace PHP code with regular expressions

Tags: php, notepad++, regex

I would like to update some PHP code into the Joomla framework, replacing things like:

```
$myvar=$_POST["myvar"];
```

with

```
$myvar=JRequest::getVar('myvar');
```

This seems like it should be easy enough but I can't get it to work. How do I do that?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. The normal search/replace function doesn`t work for you? Do you want to batch-edit multiple files at once?

Comment: Yes, many files with $_POST and $_GET needing to be replaced, and $_SESSION too.

Comment: Normal search lets me replace the $_POST[" then I have to carefully do the "] - usually miss one or two.

Comment: For that you would need capture groups. Can't test on N++ right now, but [this short guide](http://studioshorts.com/blog/2010/08/using-regular-expressions-captured-groups-in-notepad-find-and-replace/) should get you started.

Comment: What I have found:

find: \$_POST\["([\w\s]+)"\];

replace: JRequest::getVar('\1',''); //$_POST["\1"];

The original code is preserved at the end of the line and rem'd out

Comment: Don, looks like you found your own answer :-). If you post it below *as an answer*, you can accept it (two days from now) and get this question marked as answered :-)

Answer (score 0):

Search for

```
$_POST\["([^"]+)"\]
```

and replace with

```
JRequest::getVar('\1')
```

`\["([^"]+)"\]` To match the square brackets literally, they need to be escaped using a backslash.

`[^"]` means every character, but not a `"`.

`([^"]+)` the round brackets put the found stuff into a capturing group, this could then be retrieved with `\1` (used in the replacement)